# Angular Currency Converter, undefined response from HTTP

Tags: angular, http, typescript

Im trying to create a currency converter in Angular. I did fine by myself following a tutorial where the exchanges rates were predetermined. Now I want to get the exchanges rate from an API using the http module, but it seems that I'm getting an undefined value because my exchange rate is displayed as NaN in my html.
The currency convertor works with a select option where the user can pick any currency that they want. If I pick EUR/GBP I get NaN as exchange rate, which is the value I get from the service.

Thanks for your help!

app.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AllRatesService } from './allrates.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="baseAmount"
      [class.error]="isInvalid(baseAmount)">
    <currency-select [(selected)]="baseCurrency"></currency-select>
    = <strong>{{targetAmount | fixed:2}}</strong>
    <currency-select [(selected)]="targetCurrency"></currency-select>
    <p *ngIf="isInvalid(baseAmount)">Please enter a valid amount</p>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  baseCurrency = 'USD';
  targetCurrency = 'GBP';
  baseAmount = 1;
  clpbtc: number;

  constructor(private rateService: AllRatesService) { }

  private exchangeRates = {
      "EUR/GBP": this.clpbtc,
      "EUR/USD": 1.1397,
      "GBP/EUR": 1.2478,
      "GBP/USD": 1.4225,
      "USD/EUR": 0.8778,
      "USD/GBP": 0.7029
    };

  get targetAmount() {
    const exchangeRate = this.getExchangeRate(this.baseCurrency, this.targetCurrency);
    return this.baseAmount * exchangeRate;
  }

  getExchangeRate(baseCurrency: string, targetCurrency: string) {
    if (baseCurrency === targetCurrency) {
      return 1;
    }
    return this.exchangeRates[baseCurrency +'/'+ targetCurrency];
  }

  isInvalid(value) {
    return !Number.isFinite(value);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rateService.getClpBtc()
    .subscribe(prices => {
      this.clpbtc = prices.ticker.min_ask[0];
    })
  }
}
```

currency-select.component

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { AllRatesService } from './allrates.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'currency-select',
  template: `
    <select [ngModel]="selected" (ngModelChange)="onSelectedChange($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let currency of supportedCurrencies" [value]="currency">
        {{currency}}
      </option>
    </select>
  `
})
export class CurrencySelectComponent {

  @Input() selected: string;
  @Output() selectedChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

  supportedCurrencies: string[];

  constructor(allrates: AllRatesService) {
    this.supportedCurrencies = allrates.supportedCurrencies;
  }

  onSelectedChange(selected: string) {
    this.selected = selected;
    this.selectedChange.emit(selected);
  }
}
```

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { SurbtcMarket } from './surbtcmarket';

@Injectable()
export class AllRatesService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  supportedCurrencies = ['EUR', 'GBP', 'USD'];

  public getClpBtc() :Observable<SurbtcMarket> {
    return Observable.interval(15000)
      .startWith(0)
      .switchMap(() => {
        return this.http.get('https://www.surbtc.com/api/v2/markets/btc-clp/ticker')
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you ever initialized this.clpbtc?